# Using QGIS modules on Android Studio

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-grass-plugin, qgis-android

I've been working on an Android app (using Android Studio 3.0) that utilises certain supported GRASS GIS modules that are available on QGIS. It uses the module in conjunction with open source raster maps as well as user-inputed data to create a prediction model.

I'm new to GIS.

Is there a procedure for accessing these libraries as well as the OSM and Google Earth plugins out of the QGIS framework?